# UIKitExtension file not including in UI7Kit (iOS)

Tags: ios

I am testing `UI7Kit` from [this link.](https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit)

After i download source code , i try to run it.

However the following file is not including.

```
 #import <UIKitExtension/UIKitExtension.h>
```

Anyone who have experienced about UI7Kit and how can find that source code?

Answer (score 4):

Out of curiosity I cloned the repository and it also gave me the error on build. So I did a google search for the class name and found this project, which you need to clone and reference in the project: https://github.com/youknowone/FoundationExtension

Edit: Upon further reading I realize what the problem is. You need to use CocoaPods to install the necessary framework I mentioned above: https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit#how-to-run-test-app